# python list - convert to list of list

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction along with any documentation that can provide even more info than just the answer. Here we go, I have a list of strings:

```
arr = ["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"]
```

I want to turn that list into a list of lists so that the new element will be its order of appearance

```
arr = [("abcd",1),("abcdef",1),("def",1),("abcdef",2)]
```

the reason for this is because I would like to then sort that list by length of string, and in case any are of identical length, I can use the 2nd element of the list to know which one was first from my original list.

```
when "abcdef" appears twice, it also contains 1 or 2 in its 2nd element
```

hope that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: To start you off, here's the `Counter` module: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks! I will do some more research

Comment: I don't understand the reason you're describing. Why exactly can't you just sort the strings by length? What bad thing would happen?

Comment: @Paul - I appreciate that... I will do some reading there!

Comment: @StefanPochmann what if I am sorting by string length, and its two identical length strings, but they are different? as in "abc" and "def", both are length 3 but one appeared first

Comment: Stemming is stripping overlap in words, though, which is not what it looks like you want. Overall, the question in unclear. Why do you need to know the positions that the elements occur in the original list.

Comment: @antonio_zeus Well what about it? Where's the problem?

Comment: Dunno why my answer gets down voted: it answers the final goal of OP: `sorted(["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"], key=len)` in case of identical lengeth the element come in input order.

Comment: @JulienBernu Your answer sorts by length, not "order of appearance"

Comment: @cricket_007 Jeez read the question!  "the reason for this is because I would like to then sort that list by length of string, and in case any are of identical length, I can use the 2nd element of the list to know which one was first from my original list." Is it me or what???

Comment: @JulienBernu I'm with you, but OP keeps avoiding my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple and pythonic.

```
[(v, lst[:i].count(v)+1) for i,v in enumerate(lst)]
```

where `lst` is your list.

```
>>> lst = ["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"]
>>> [(v, lst[:i].count(v)+1) for i,v in enumerate(lst)]
[('abcd', 1), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 1), ('abcdef', 2)]
```

Comment: Stop downvoting other answers otherwise I shall report you.

Comment: A. J.  The other 2 answers (not yours) were purely incorrect.  IMO, yours is complete not-pythonic, as it does something in 9 lines as mine does in 1.

Comment: So? It answers the question so it does not merit a downvote... Just because one solution is shorter doesn't mean the poster needs to downvote the rest

Comment: Shorter is not better.  @A.J. algorithm is more efficient.

Comment: Simply adding the enumerate value identifies the original order as well:  `[(a,i) for i,a in enumerate(arr)]`.  `[('abcd', 0), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 2), ('abcdef', 3)]`.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't think so. `[('abcd', 1), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 1), ('abcdef', 2)]` is not the same thing as `[('abcd', 0), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 2), ('abcdef', 3)]`.

Comment: The numbers are different, but they convey just as much order information.  1-2, 1-3.  The OP just needs assurance that sort does not switch the order of equal items.

Comment: I don't understand your point, and I especially don't understand how it justifies a DV.

Comment: Would all the people who DV mind dropping a comment?

Comment: DV rarely explain their action. Just move on.

Comment: why this is the answer when AJ's answer has 4 upvotes?

Comment: @HaifengZhang the check mark means that it solved the OP's problem. Also, this answer was +3 at one time but people downvoted it for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following for loop:

```
>>> arr = ["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"]
>>> counts = {}
>>> new = []
>>> for item in arr:
...     if item not in counts:
...             new.append((item, 1))
...             counts[item] = 1
...     else:
...             counts[item]+=1
...             new.append((item, counts[item]))
... 
>>> new
[('abcd', 1), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 1), ('abcdef', 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: I think you can just do `if item not in counts:` on line 5, no need for `keys()`.

Answer (score 3):

Python's sort is stable, per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort):

> The sort() method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal

So just sort the list like the deleted answer of @JulienBernu:

```
>>> sorted(["abcd","abcdeg","def","abcdef"], key=len)
['def', 'abcd', 'abcdeg', 'abcdef']
>>> sorted(["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdeg"], key=len)
['def', 'abcd', 'abcdef', 'abcdeg']
```

Note that the items of equal length remain in the original order.  You don't need to track it.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was getting crazy... any way to report those undeserved downvotes?

Comment: I find it is better to give the OP want they want rather than convince them of what they need. That was the point I was getting at.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are totally right: I must have told the OP to write "the reason for this is because I would like to then sort that list by length of string, and in case any are of identical length, I can use the 2nd element of the list to know which one was first from my original list." I give up with you dude!

Comment: What if the list has a lot of items of the same length? They will all appear in the same order, not in the order of appearance in the list. Try your solution with `arr = ["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef", "aba", "dad", "zzz", "oop", "def", "123", "def"]`. But @cricket_007 solution works.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen thanks for this answer... it exaplins sort a lot better than I thought!

Comment: @chapelo I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  Items with the same length will appear in the same relative order they appeared in the original list...even with your example.

Comment: @chapelo note the OP's comment *after* his example: "the reason for this is because I would like to then sort that list by length of string, and in case any are of identical length, I can use the 2nd element of the list to know which one was first from my original list"

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"], key=len)` will do the job.

Comment: @cricket_007 "the reason for this is because I would like to then sort that list by length of string, and in case any are of identical length, I can use the 2nd element of the list to know which one was first from my original list." Doesn't my answer give solve the final goal?

Comment: I suppose, for the sorting part, yes, but it doesn't solve how it uses the second element to know which order the original list had

Comment: @cricket_007 The order is left as it's inputted in case of identical length!

Answer (score 0):

this look like a job for [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> arr = ["abcd","abcdef","def","abcdef"]
>>> result = []
>>> current_count = Counter()
>>> for x in arr:
        current_count[x] += 1
        result.append( (x,current_count[x]) )

>>> result
[('abcd', 1), ('abcdef', 1), ('def', 1), ('abcdef', 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: You are using the `Counter` as a mere `dict`. You are doing the counting, not the `Counter`. You might as well use a `dict` or `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: @chapelo I have to do it that way if I am going to preserve the order of the original list, and I choice `Counter` over the others because it already work with numbers by definition and go with semantics of the code